# Obtaining Least square adjusted single line by intersecting many 3D planes

Tags: c++, geometry, computational-geometry, vector-graphics, eigenvector

I am working with many 3D planes and looking for a Least square solution for below case.

> IF I am having many number of 3D planes knowing only one point and the
> normal vector (for eg. O1 and N1), and all those planes intersect each
> other and make nearly very close 3d lines, then how to compute the
> least square adjusted one single 3d line to represent all those
> intersections.

To get a clear idea, I have inserted a figure.

- Known: one point and the normal vector of each plane.
- Find: Least Square fitted single line3d

[image]

as i want to do this with c++, i use c++ tag too.

Comment: That's an analytical geometry question, not a programming question. I'm sure there are more appropriate forums even within StackExchange to ask this question.

Comment: It also seems somewhat difficult. Planes intersect in lines so how are you defining your distance function? The point of nearest approach of two 3-d lines?

Comment: Just sprinkle some points along your pairwise intersection lines, and calculate the least squares from the points.

Comment: @Will Ness: Yes I was thinking to get pair wise intersection. Then I heard it can be done directly with least square without intersecting pairwise. so i wish to adopt that way. but no clear idea how least sqaure question should be built with the given variables.

Comment: @TheMathemagician: Sorry, for my poor math, i cannot figure out an answer for you.

Comment: let's number the planes, 1,2,3,...n... . The intersection lines are 12, ... 19, ... 34, ... . If we only consider pairs of lines `ij,jk`, they are guaranteed to lie in one plane, viz. `j`. Their least-squares "middle" is a line, going thru their intersection point, at mid-angle between them. See if you can do anything with that.

Comment: @Will Ness: yes, that is true. But to be honest, I am looking for the other way of doing this with least squares. for example i found this paper (in section 3): http://www.ipb.uni-bonn.de/uploads/tx_ikgpublication/heuel01.matching.pdf but unfortuately, i cannot figure out the things from the basic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entirely untested.

What if you took the directions of the lines from the intersections and got the [Principle Component](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis)

This would get you the direction they're going in. Then create a plane using that direction and an arbitrary point, Project all the points from the plane intersection calculations onto the plane, and find the mean point of these projected points.

Use that mean point and the principle component to define your line.

Something like...

```
class Plane
{
public:
    Vector3 Point;
    Vector3 Normal;

    Line Intersect (const Plane &other);

    Vector3 Project (const Vector3 &point);
}

class Line
{
public:
    Vector3 Point;
    Vector3 Direction;

    Line (Vector3 point, Vector3 dir);

};

Vector3 PrincipleComponent (const std::vector<Line> &lines)
{
    //You could use the covariance matrix to get this but I will try the interative method on wikipedia.
    Vector3 p(1,2,3); //a random vector?
    static const int c = 10;
    for (int i = 0; i < c; ++i)
    {
        Vector3 t;
        for (auto i = lines.begin(); i != lines.end (); ++i)
        {
            t = t + ((*i).Direction.Dot (p)) * (*i).Direction;
        }
        t.Normalize();
        p = t;
    }
    return p;
}

int main ()
{
    std::vector<Line> LinesFromPlaneIntersections;


    Vector3 direction = PrincipleComponent (LinesFromPlaneIntersections);
    Plane projplane;
    projplane.Normal = direction;
    projplane.Point = LinesFromPlaneIntersections[0].Point;

    Vector3 meanpoint;
    for (auto i = LinesFromPlaneIntersections.begin(); i != LinesFromPlaneIntersections.end (); ++i)
    {
        meanpoint += projplane.Project ((*i).Point);
    }

    meanpoint /= LinesFromPlaneIntersections.size ();

    Line result (meanpoint,direction);
}
```